# Calculate subplot adjustment

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So I have some data calculated that now should be visualised. For each data element, I want to place a separate subplot so that the whole figure is as compact as possible. Here's an example for five elements:

[image: 2x3 subplots for five data elements]

Here's a prototype I came up with for an arbitrary elements count:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

data = ... # some list of pairs of numpy arrays, for x and y axes
size = len(data)
cols = math.floor(math.sqrt(size))
rows = math.ceil(size / cols)

f, diags = plt.subplots(rows, cols)

for (row, col), diag in np.ndenumerate(diags):
    dataIdx = row * cols + col
    if dataIdx < size:
        x = data[dataIdx][0]
        y = data[dataIdx][1]
        diag.scatter(x, y)
        diag.set_title('Regressor {}'.format(dataIdx + 1))
    else: # discard empty subplots
        f.delaxes(diag)
f.show()
```

A short explanation: for compactness, I'm trying to adjust the plots in form of a square matrix if possible. If not, I add another row for the remaining diagrams. Then I iterate the diagrams, calculate the according position of data element and plot its values. If no data element is found for the diagram, it means the diagram is a remainder from the last row and can be discarded.

However, this is the code I would probably write in C++ or Java, the question is, what would the the pythonic way?

Also, what would be the best solution for this when iterating over data instead of diagrams? I could of course calculate the diagram's row/column from the element index the same way I did in the initial rows/columns calculation, but maybe there's a better way to do this...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is a quadratic matrix?

Comment: Ehm, a square matrix I somehow managed to name quadratic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would likely create the plot like this:

```
size = len(data)
cols = round(math.sqrt(size))
rows = cols
while rows * cols < size:
    rows += 1
f, ax_arr = plt.subplots(rows, cols)
ax_arr = ax_arr.reshape(-1)
for i in range(len(ax_arr)):
    if i >= size:
        ax_arr[i].axis('off')
    x = data[i][0]
    y = data[i][1]
    ax_arr[i].scatter(x,y)
```

Comment: reshaping axes is a brilliant idea!